# Fetch the colum and row which has the Max value for the row

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
table: |name|US|IN|SA|CHN|AU|EU|.......
       |john|0 |12|2 |0  |1 |0 |.......
       |andy|20|17|2 |10 |1 |0 |.......
```

I have a table with 200 columns having all countries. In them are the entries in integer of the number of clicks coming from each country. In order to display them in a geo chart I would like to parse these values in such a way as follows:

output:

```
IN,12
SA,2
AU,1
```

such that I would like to **exlude** those countries that have **0** clicks and grouped by username **john**

Here is my method but it is incomplete..

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM `countries`";


    $result = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM `countries`.`graph_geo_table` WHERE Field NOT IN ('Name')");
    if (!$result) {
        echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
        exit;
    }

if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    echo $row[Field];

    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you to create separate countries table and make a link between users and countries. Normally, storing 200 columns is a bad idea since it's scalability is very poor

Comment: but even if i store..is there a way to display only the row fields that do not contain 0?

Comment: Well, yes, it is. Something like `SELECT users.name, user_countries.value, countries.name FROM users LEFT JOIN users_countries ON users.id=users_countries.user_id LEFT JOIN countries ON users_countries.country_id=countries.id WHERE users_countries.value>0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this

```sql
SELECT column_name country,
       CASE column_name
       WHEN 'US'  THEN us
       WHEN 'IN'  THEN `in`
       WHEN 'SA'  THEN sa
       WHEN 'CHN' THEN chn
       WHEN 'AU'  THEN au
       WHEN 'EU'  THEN eu
       END clicks
  FROM Table1 t CROSS JOIN
(
  SELECT COLUMN_NAME
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
   WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Table1'
     AND TABLE_SCHEMA = SCHEMA()
     AND COLUMN_NAME <> 'name'
) c  
 WHERE name = 'john'
HAVING clicks > 0
 ORDER BY clicks DESC
```

Output:

```
| COUNTRY | CLICKS |
|---------|--------|
|      IN |     12 |
|      SA |      2 |
|      AU |      1 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/42756/5)** demo

Comment: hello sir! most of all thank you for such an elaborate answer.Suppose if another user 'andy' registers is there a way to fetch values for andy with the same country and clicks(I have edited the question)

Comment: @googledev You're very welcome :) If you want to get data for one name at a time just add `WHERE` clause. See updated answer. If you on the other hand want to see clicks counts for two or more names side-by-side than it is different story.